# In Ruby, how can I get instance variables in a hash instead of an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, instance-variables

I have a Ruby class.  I want to get an instance variable from an argument to a method in that class.  I can do get all of the instance variables as an array:

```
self.instance_variables
```

However, I want to get the instance variable named `arg`, specifically:

```
class MyClass
  def get_instance_variable(arg)
    hash_of_instance_variables[arg]
  end
end

object.get_instance_variable('my_instance_var')
```

How do I compute `hash_of_instance_variables`?

Comment: Can you elaborate? Your question is not very clear.

Comment: It looks like you're hoping to build a hash that maps instance variables to their values so that you can retrieve the value of the instance variable.  If so, why?  Use `instance_variable_get`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To create a hash of all instance variables you can use the following code:

```
class Object
  def instance_variables_hash
    Hash[instance_variables.map { |name| [name, instance_variable_get(name)] } ]
  end
end
```

But as *cam* mentioned in his comment, you should use `instance_variable_get` method instead:

```
object.instance_variable_get :@my_instance_var
```

Answer (score 13):

Question is quite old but found rails solution for this: [instance_values](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/Object/instance_values)

This is first answer in google so maybe it will help someone.

Comment: Thanks for helping the community. I no longer use ruby/rails, moved on to node.js. Bests

Comment: The code used by Rails is almost identical to the accepted answer with the exception that Rails strips the leading `@`.

Comment: `instance_values` worked for me and was simpler. Thanks! (now tested with Rails 6)

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyClass    
def variables_to_hash
      h = {}
      instance_variables.each{|a|
        s = a.to_s
        n = s[1..s.size]
        v = instance_variable_get a
        h[n] = v
      }
      h
    end
end
```

Comment: Note that `s[1..s.size]` can be replaced with `s[1..-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

For Ruby 2.6+, you can [pass a block to the `to_h` method](https://rubyreferences.github.io/rubychanges/2.6.html#to_h-with-a-block), leading to very DRY syntax:

```rb
# Some instance variables
instance_variable_set(:@a, 'dog')
#=> "dog"
instance_variable_set(:@b, 'cat')
#=> "cat"

# Array of instance variable names
instance_variables
#=> [:@a, :@b]

# Hash of instance variable names and values, including leading @
instance_variables.to_h { |k| [k, instance_variable_get(k)] }
#=> { :@a => "dog", :@b => "cat" }

# Hash of instance variable names and values, excluding leading @
instance_variables.to_h { |k| [k[1..-1].to_sym, instance_variable_get(k)] }
#=> { :a => "dog", :b => "cat" }
```

Answer (score -1):

Ruby on Rails has a couple of built-in ways to do this that you might find meet your needs.

> user = User.new(first: 'brian', last: 'case')

- **attributes** ([Rails API: ActiveModel::AttributeMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/AttributeMethods.html))

> user.attributes
>
> {"first"=>"brian", "last"=>"case"}

- **serializable_hash** ([Rails API: Active Model Serialization](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Serialization.html#method-i-to_xml))

> user.serializeable_hash
>
> {"first"=>"brian", "last"=>"case"}

Comment: This only applies to Rails models (instances of `ActiveRecord::Base`). For an arbitrary Ruby object, @sufleR's answer works.