# Ruby object vs. hash

Tags: ruby

Code snippet below returns an object.

```
class Person
  def initialize(name, gender)
    @name = name
    @gender = gender
  end
end
x = Person.new("Dan", "M")
=> #<Person:0x007f6f96600560 @name="Dan", @gender="M">
```

- What is the difference between an object `< ... >` and a hash `{ ... }`? Why wouldn't a Ruby class just return hashes?
- What is the `0x007f6f96600560` in the object? I am pretty sure it's not `object_id`.

Comment: `0x00...` is `(object_id << 1).to_s(16)` (`object_id`, shifted left by one in 16 numeral base.) About what the object is in OOP there are tons of books written. You should not expect to receive an answer on SO for this sort of questions, for that people study years and read many books.

Comment: The OP seems to be implicitly suggesting that all classes should be subclassed from `Hash`, and instance variable names and values be stored as key-value pairs in them. In fact, JavaScript works somewhat like that.

Comment: Short answer : because Ruby isn't a [prototype-based language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming).

Comment: @EricDuminil Thanks! Short and to the point. So is it boiled down to choice of design? That is, prototype-based design would have worked for Ruby via re-use of its existing hashes, just as how Javascript re-uses existing objects as prototypes, but Ruby ultimately adopted the class-based design?

Answer (score 7):

## Object → Hash

From the excellent book ["Ruby under the microscope"](http://patshaughnessy.net/ruby-under-a-microscope) by Pat Shaughnessy :

> Every Ruby object is the combination of a class pointer and an array
>   of instance variables.

[Here](http://siawyoung.com/coding/ruby/ruby-objects.html)'s a somewhat longer description :

> A user-defined Ruby object is represented by a structure called an
>   RObject, and is referred to by a pointer called VALUE.
>
> Inside RObject, there is another structure called RBasic, which all
>   Ruby values will have.
>
> Aside from the RBasic structure, RObject also contains numiv, a count
>   of how many instance variables the object has, ivptr, a pointer to an
>   array of values of the instance variables, and iv_index_tbl, which is
>   a pointer to a hash table stored in the object’s associated RClass
>   structure that maps the name/identity of each instance variable to its
>   position in the ivtpr array.

From any Ruby object, it's possible to [extract a hash of instance variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8417341/6419007) :

```
class Object
  def instance_variables_hash
    Hash[instance_variables.map { |name| [name, instance_variable_get(name)] } ]
  end
end
```

With your example :

```
x.instance_variables_hash
=> {:@name=>"Dan", :@gender=>"M"}
```

## Hash → Object ?

But you couldn't possibly create `x` back from this hash, because you're missing a crucial piece of information : what class is `x` an instance of?

So for example, you wouldn't know the methods that you can send to `x` :

```
class Dog
  def initialize(name, gender)
    @name = name
    @gender = gender
  end

  def bark
    puts "WOOF"
  end
end

person = Person.new("Dan", "M")
dog    = Dog.new("Dan", "M")

p person.instance_variables_hash
# {:@name=>"Dan", :@gender=>"M"}
p dog.instance_variables_hash == person.instance_variables_hash
# true
person.bark
# undefined method `bark' for #<Person:0x007fb3b20ed658 @name="Dan", @gender="M">
```

## object_id

To get the object_id out of the inspect string :

```
"0x007f6f96600560".sub('0x','').to_i(16)/2
#=> 70058620486320
```

And back :

```
"0x" + (70058620486320 * 2).to_s(16).rjust(14,'0')
#=> "0x007f6f96600560"
```

Answer (score 3):

Of course, some times you can use objects and hashes for the same thing. Storing key value pair ob objects like this:

```
[3] pry(main)> class Person
  def initialize(name, gender)
    @name = name
    @gender = gender
  end
end

[3] pry(main)* => :initialize

[4] pry(main)> x = Person.new("Dan", "M")
=> #<Person:0x00000003708098 @gender="M", @name="Dan">


[13] pry(main)> y = Person.new("Peter", "M")
=> #<Person:0x0000000391fca0 @gender="M", @name="Peter">


[22] pry(main)> z = {name: "Maria", gender: "F"}
=> {:name=>"Maria", :gender=>"F"}
```

But this objects really doesn't get all the power of an object oriente programming language from the definitions of an [class/object](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_classes.htm) and [hash](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_hashes.htm):

> Ruby is a perfect Object Oriented Programming Language. The features
>   of the object-oriented programming language include:
>
> ```
> Data Encapsulation:
>
> Data Abstraction:
>
> Polymorphism:
>
> Inheritance:
> ```
>
> These features have been discussed in Object Oriented Ruby.
>
> An object-oriented program involves classes and objects. A class is
>   the blueprint from which individual objects are created. In
>   object-oriented terms, we say that your bicycle is an instance of the
>   class of objects known as bicycles.
>
> Take the example of any vehicle. It comprises wheels, horsepower, and
>   fuel or gas tank capacity. These characteristics form the data members
>   of the class Vehicle. You can differentiate one vehicle from the other
>   with the help of these characteristics.
>
> A vehicle can also have certain functions, such as halting, driving,
>   and speeding. Even these functions form the data members of the class
>   Vehicle. You can, therefore, define a class as a combination of
>   characteristics and functions.

and a hash:

> A Hash is a collection of key-value pairs like this: "employee" =>
>   "salary". It is similar to an Array, except that indexing is done via
>   arbitrary keys of any object type, not an integer index.

So for store data I recommend you a Hash.

On the other hand, as showed in a comment the number that appers in the object representation is the object id, but with few operations added:

1) bitwise left shift:

```
5 << 1  # gives 10
```

2) passed to hexadeimal

```
(10).to_s(16)

"a"

pry(main)> x = Person.new("Dan", "M")
=> #<Person:0x00000003708098 @gender="M", @name="Dan">
[5] pry(main)> x.object_id
=> 28852300
[8] pry(main)> (x.object_id << 1 ).to_s(16)
=> "3708098"
```

finally in ruby you can get the hash representation of an object like this:

```
x.instance_variables.each {|var| hash[var.to_s.delete("@")] = x.instance_variable_get(var) }
```